Absolute distance betwen two objects
I need help in finding the absolute distance between two objects in the following scenario. One object is moving along a semi-circular path in the z-axis, while the other object is stationary and has a fixed position in the x-y plane (please see the attached figure). Looking from top, as the first object moves, the absolute distance between both objects changes. I was wondering if someone could help me identify the relationship that would enable me to calculate the distance between both objects. Thank you.
Screenshot:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please find attached image that clarifies my problem better. I am trying to estimate variable d.

I'm not sure you need a z-axis here (there isn't one on the diagram you have showing both objects). What you need are the coordinates of both objects. I'm guessing you already know the fixed one. Can you work out the coordinates of the one on the semicircle in terms of $\theta$? (You'll also need the radius of the semicircle). Once you have both sets of coordinates, you can use Pythagoras to get the distance between them.

yes, you are right z-axis is not needed. I know the radius of arch and I did exactly what you have suggested i..e, a=(0-(0+radcosd(theta))).^2; b= (0-(dist_to_ant+(radsind(theta)))).^2; distance=sqrt(a+b); where a and b are calculate two sides of a traiangle, rad is the radius of arch. However, the results are not correct in comparison to what I had physically measured


Convert the coordinates if the triangle object from polar to cartesian with $$\begin{aligned} x_1 & = r \cos \theta \\ y_1 & = r \sin \theta \end{aligned}$$

Take the Eucledian distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ the coordinates of the rectanlge object
$${\rm dist} = \sqrt{ (x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 }$$


